# Writing Code in MArkup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a template field in a gridview with a label whose text I want to alter depending on an if statement. The Following of course does not work but this is what i want to accomplish.

```
 <%if Eval("Address") != ""%>
    <%{ %>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label18" nowrap="nowrap" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") + "<br>" + Eval("City") + "," + Eval("State") + " " + Eval("Zip1") + " " + Eval("Zip2") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
  <%} %>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label18" nowrap="nowrap" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") != String.Empty ? Eval("Address") + "<br>" + Eval("City") + "," + Eval("State") + " " + Eval("Zip1") + " " + Eval("Zip2") : String.Empty %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: i really like this idea. But it still goes through the code. I tried String.IsnullorEmpty but that didn't work either

Comment: I've never seen this approach - but how can i use it if the value is null?

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Address"))

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `DisplayAddress` property on your datasource - which is either the `Address` concatenation that you want or null/blank.

Not knowing how your binding your grid, I can't advise on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a placeholder in your itemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phAddress" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

For your gridview, have an `OnRowDataBound` event where you can construct a new `asp:Label` or plain HTML. Use the `e.Row.DataItem` to find the address details that you need.

Then you can assign that label or HTML string to `phAddress`.

[This related answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814148/asp-net-display-images-and-pdf-in-a-gridview/1814644#1814644).